# Video card does not work in server

Tags: video, hardware

I want to install a video card into a server. When it is inserted, server does not boot up and there is no video signal coming from video card. 4 LEDs at the back of the motherboard show pattern G-R-R-A which means "Disabling the console controller" (see Appendix C in manual). There was another (older) video card in that PCI slot and it worked fine. The card which I want to install works too (I tested it in another computer). Both On-board Video and Dual Monitor Video options are turned off in BIOS (when I turn on one or both options, both new and old video cards dont work). What should I try to do? Thanks.

Video card: 339PCI-HLP (2 x DVI + HDMI)

Server board: Intel S5000PAL - http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/s5000pal/sb/s5000pal_s5000xal_tps_r2_0.pdf

Comment: Ohhh I had a lot of servers based on the S5000PAL, they're normally pretty good... I don't recall the functionality of its PCI-e slots though.

Comment: It's a server?  Then you probably don't want to install a dual-DVI+HDMI card in it.  Put that card in your workstation.  The server shouldn't even have a GUI installed.

Comment: @ghoti, there are legitimate reasons to put a video card into a server.  For example if you wanted to support [RemoteFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RemoteFX).

Comment: @ghoti - or number crunching with CUDA

Comment: Ah, CUDA seems reasonable.  Still, I'd probably want to dedicate hardware to that sort of thing, rather than loading it on to server that already has other responsibilities.  Many eggs, one basket.  I don't buy the RemoteFX argument though.

Comment: @user152576: You should edit your answer with the solution to it if it's solved instead of removing the answer.

Comment: @petrus - I've restored the original content

Comment: @user152576 - please give your solution the checkmark, so that your question can be helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

See here, http://www.jaton.com/vga/graphics_card_detail.php?pid=199 I verified your card is a PCI card.

Your motherboard supports,

One low profile riser slot supporting 1U or 2U PCIe* riser cards
One full height riser slot supporting 1U or 2U PCI-X* and PCIe* riser cards

I'm not sure if your card is a 3.3v PCI card to be supported in the adaptive PCI-X slot. You have to plug-in your card only on the adaptive slot since it is both PCI-X and PCI-E

You could damage both your graphics card and your serverboard if you plug in into the wrong slot (PCIe).  Try a PCIe card in the PCIe slot if you have one around.

Also, are you using any riser cards to plug the PCI card into?

Comment: 1) There are two riser cards and I plug that PCI video card into PCI-X slot on riser card. Video card that was installed there before, was plugged in this slot. 2) There are two keys on PCI connector of video card, which means that it supports both 3.3V and 5V versions.

Comment: 3) It is impossible to insert that card into a wrong slot (PCI will not fit into PCI-express) or a wrong way (metal bracket will not let you insert the card backwards).

Comment: PCI card will fit into PCI-X slot not PCIe

Comment: Yes, I plugged PCI card into PCI-X slot.

Comment: These things are hard to debug if you aren't in front of the system. I'd say try a PCIe card if you have one around or stick to the older card that is working. Another thing I'd also suggest is to ensure the output on BIOS (if there is one) to set it to DVI/HDMI. Some BIOS defualt it on onboard Video (I know you mentioend u disabled onboard video). Do you hear any beeps with the new card?

Answer (score 0):

Yay, I made it! There was an option in BIOS which determines amount of memory available to PCI cards. It was set to 3.50Gb-4Gb, so old card with 256Mb of memory fit in that 512Mb space well. But new 1Gb card did not. So I had to change that option to 2.50-4Gb so new card could it into 1.5Gb space.

Comment: Not sure what you did to fix it, but this is almost assuredly not what fixed it.  If your card has memory, you don't need to dedicate system memory to the card.  That option is for onboard cards that don't have their own memory or cards that might need more memory than they have built in.  How much memory does the system have installed?  How much does the OS see?